# Linq Lambda Expression to return order by total

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, lambda

I have a table like below

```
   Customers  
   Id jan feb mar apr.........dec  
   1   10 12  12  10 .........40   
   2   11 13  12  10 .........42
```

I want to write Linq Expression to return order by total(jan+feb...dec) desc
I want something like `customers.OrderbyDesc(p=>Sum(p.jan,p.feb,.p.dec)`.

Note: There is no total column at the end.
If there is a way I can project the sum into temp variable and then sort it?

Comment: Which kind of table you mentioned? DataTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - something like:

```
var ordered = customers.OrderByDescending(p => p.jan + p.feb + p.mar + ...);
```

You don't need to use `Sum` here... just normal addition.